# Как показать на странице только последний загруженный файл? Как удалять остальные showfilebox перед созданием нового?

Tags: javascript, файлы, загрузка

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.checkout-file input');
const filewrapper = document.querySelector('.filewrapper');

input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let fileName = e.target.files[0].name.replace(/\.[^.$]+$/, '');

  fileshow(fileName);
})
const fileshow = (fileName) => {
  const showfileboxElem = document.createElement('div');
  showfileboxElem.classList.add('showfilebox');
  const leftElem = document.createElement('div');
  leftElem.classList.add('left');
  const fileImg = document.createElement('img')
  fileImg.src = 'img/svg/file.svg'

  leftElem.append(fileImg);
  const filetitleElem = document.createElement('h3');
  filetitleElem.classList.add('goods-info-text')
  filetitleElem.innerHTML = fileName;
  leftElem.append(filetitleElem);
  showfileboxElem.append(leftElem);
  const rightElem = document.createElement('div');
  rightElem.classList.add('right');
  showfileboxElem.append(rightElem);
  const crossElem = document.createElement('img');
  crossElem.src = 'img/svg/file-remove.svg'
  rightElem.append(crossElem);
  filewrapper.append(showfileboxElem);

  crossElem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    filewrapper.removeChild(showfileboxElem);
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="checkout-file">
  <input type="file" id="upload" hidden>
  <label for="upload" class="uploadlabel">
    <img src="img/svg/checkout-file.svg" alt="">
    <div class="goods-info-text opacity">Добавить документ</div>
  </label>


  <div class="filewrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: при загрузке файла создает следующий код:
`<div class="filewrapper">
<div class="showfilebox">
  <div class="left">
   <img src="img/svg/file.svg">
   <h3 class="goods-info-text">package</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="right"><img src="img/svg/file-remove.svg"></div>
 </div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого нужно очищать блок `filewrapper` при каждом выборе файла если в ней есть лишние блоки:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.checkout-file input');
const filewrapper = document.querySelector('.filewrapper');

input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
    let fileName = e.target.files[0].name.replace(/\.[^.$]+$/, '');
    fileshow(fileName);
  }
});

const fileshow = (fileName) => {
  // Очищаем блок filewrapper
  filewrapper.innerHTML = "";
  // Далее как раньше
  const showfileboxElem = document.createElement('div');
  showfileboxElem.classList.add('showfilebox');
  const leftElem = document.createElement('div');
  leftElem.classList.add('left');
  const fileImg = document.createElement('img')
  fileImg.src = 'img/svg/file.svg'

  leftElem.append(fileImg);
  const filetitleElem = document.createElement('h3');
  filetitleElem.classList.add('goods-info-text')
  filetitleElem.innerHTML = fileName;
  leftElem.append(filetitleElem);
  showfileboxElem.append(leftElem);
  const rightElem = document.createElement('div');
  rightElem.classList.add('right');
  showfileboxElem.append(rightElem);
  const crossElem = document.createElement('img');
  crossElem.src = 'img/svg/file-remove.svg'
  rightElem.append(crossElem);
  filewrapper.append(showfileboxElem);

  crossElem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    filewrapper.removeChild(showfileboxElem);
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="checkout-file">
  <input type="file" id="upload" hidden>
  <label for="upload" class="uploadlabel">
    <img src="img/svg/checkout-file.svg" alt="">
    <div class="goods-info-text opacity">Добавить документ</div>
  </label>


  <div class="filewrapper"></div>
</div>
```